# Создание датасета tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Имеется большой датасет (73 гб). В нем иерархия папок и файлов, а так же map файл. Как сделать датасет в формате npy?

Comment: В каком формате сохранены файлы датасета?

Comment: @MaxU map - txt, photo - jpeg. Сжаты в bin всё в общем.